# Pandas Pivot table keeping the table intact

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Say we have following table

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'col1': list('abcadeabba'),
    'col2': range(10),
    'col3': [list('abc'), list('d'), list('e'), list('ba'), list('de'),
             list('abc'), list('ae'), list('e'), list('dc'), list('a')]
})
df
```

[image]

I need to `col1` values as the columns, and the values under the new columns would be based on `col3` with default value 0; Columns corresponding to `col3` values should be 1 and others new columns values should be 0 in the row. Also, `col2` should be as it is.

So, the first row would look like below
[image]

I tried `pivot_table` but did not find the efficient way to populate values using `col3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) for good performance solution and then append to original with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by unique values of `col1`, if not exist column is added `0` column(s):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['col3']),columns=mlb.classes_)
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  1
3  1  1  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  1  1
5  1  1  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0  1
7  0  0  0  0  1
8  0  0  1  1  0
9  1  0  0  0  0


df = df.join(df1.reindex(df['col1'].unique(), fill_value=0, axis=1))
print (df)
  col1  col2       col3  a  b  c  d  e
0    a     0  [a, b, c]  1  1  1  0  0
1    b     1        [d]  0  0  0  1  0
2    c     2        [e]  0  0  0  0  1
3    a     3     [b, a]  1  1  0  0  0
4    d     4     [d, e]  0  0  0  1  1
5    e     5  [a, b, c]  1  1  1  0  0
6    a     6     [a, e]  1  0  0  0  1
7    b     7        [e]  0  0  0  0  1
8    b     8     [d, c]  0  0  1  1  0
9    a     9        [a]  1  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: This works for me. But we are not using col1 to create columns - which might cause issue if the particualar col1 values do not appear in col3?

Comment: @ggaurav - answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'col1': list('abcadeabba'),
    'col2': range(10),
    'col3': [list('abc'), list('d'), list('e'), list('ba'), list('de'),
             list('abc'), list('ae'), list('e'), list('dc'), list('a')]
})

dummies_ = pd.get_dummies(df['col3'].explode())

print(pd.concat([df, dummies_.groupby(dummies_.index).sum()], axis=1))
```

---

```
  col1  col2       col3  a  b  c  d  e
0    a     0  [a, b, c]  1  1  1  0  0
1    b     1        [d]  0  0  0  1  0
2    c     2        [e]  0  0  0  0  1
3    a     3     [b, a]  1  1  0  0  0
4    d     4     [d, e]  0  0  0  1  1
5    e     5  [a, b, c]  1  1  1  0  0
6    a     6     [a, e]  1  0  0  0  1
7    b     7        [e]  0  0  0  0  1
8    b     8     [d, c]  0  0  1  1  0
9    a     9        [a]  1  0  0  0  0
```